# Как выровнять блок div по правой стороне?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, так чтобы блок nav был выровнен по правой стороне блока header?

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="images/logo-01.png" id="logo" width="200" height="75">
    <div id="nav">
        <span class="navclass">How It Works</span>
        <span class="navclass">Feature Tour</span>
        <span class="navclass">Get Started</span>
        <span class="navclass">Plugins</span>
        <span class="navclass">Developers</span>
        <span class="navclass">Blog</span>
        <span class="navclass">Support</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vhLAz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне нравиться больше вариант делать так:

```
 #header{ position: relative}
 #nav{ position: absolute; right:0px}
```

Это просто по опыту работает стабильнее и быстрее. И да, нужно родителю задать высоту, но в вашем случае она уже есть.

Можно, конечно, использовать #{float: right}, но потом может появиться спец-эффект: ширина #header будет равна максимальной высоте из сыновей, у которых нет обтекания (float). Для этого после #nav надо добавить элемент со свойством: clear:both

Кстати в верстке принято писать ul вместо div#nav. И вместо span li . И нужно пофиксить отступы будет. Это считается более семантично.

Answer (score 3):

```
#nav{
float:right
}
```

Не вариант?

Comment: Разберитесь с какой стороны должен быть выровнен блок. С правой или с левой?

Comment: а если бы не было логотипа, то нижние блоки начнут обтекать nav. какие нить еще варианты есть?

Comment: а что мешает у нижних блоков прописать float: none и clear: both?